# Overriding of bean coming from external library

Tags: java, spring

If I have a project in which I have a dependency on a library in which a bean’s scope is unspecified, meaning singleton by default, is there a way to override the bean definition to keep it the same but only change the scope to prototype, either at runtime or through bean configuration?

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura I'm not sure I understand how having my own FactoryBean allows me to change/override the scope of the bean at runtime

Answer (score 5):

There are three cases:

- If bean which you want to override is in configuration class marked
  with @Confgiuration annotation , you can exclude this configuration
  class and declare all beans from there
- If annotation is present directly on class than you should exclude
  those class from @ComponentScan basePackages .
- You can set the order of configuration classes marked with
  @Configuration annotation , the last one configuration class will
  override all previous declared beans